# Using Laravel eloquent calculate total of like and passing into vue js file

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vue.js

Currently i am implementing a like system into my laravel project with Vue js. The scenario is after users liked the post. It will showing the total like of the post beside the like button. If using controller and passing data into view is easy to be done. But when change to Vue js i have no idea how to do it. This is my Like.vue file.

```
<template>

<button class="btn btn-primary" v-if="!auth_user_likes_post" @click="like()">
    Support
</button>

<button class="btn btn-primary" v-else @click="unlike()">
    Unsupport
</button>
```

```
export default {
    mounted(){

    },

    props: ['id'],

    computed: {
        likers() {
            var likers = []

            this.post.likes.forEach( (like) => {
                likers.push(like.user.id)
            })
            return likers
        },
        auth_user_likes_post() {
            var check_index = this.likers.indexOf(
                this.$store.state.auth_user.id
            )
            if (check_index === -1)
                return false
            else
                return true
        },
        post() {
            return this.$store.state.posts.find( (post) => {
                return post.id === this.id
            })
        }
    },
    methods: {
        like() {
            this.$http.get('/like/' + this.id)
                .then( (resp) => {
                    this.$store.commit('update_post_likes', {
                        id: this.id,
                        like: resp.body
                    })

                })
        },
        unlike() {
            this.$http.get('/unlike/' + this.id)
                .then( (response) => {
                    this.$store.commit('unlike_post', {
                        post_id: this.id,
                        like_id: response.body
                    })
                })
        }
    }
}
```

The like and unlike functions has been done and working perfectly. Now i just need to show the total number.

This is Feed.vue file. The like was adding to this page.

```
<div class="post-description">
                    <p>{{ post.content }}</p>
                    <div class="stats">
                        <like :id="post.id"></like>
                        <a href="#" class="stat-item">
                            <i class="fa fa-retweet icon"></i>12
                        </a>
                        <a href="#" class="stat-item">
                            <i class="fa fa-comments-o icon"></i>3
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

If my function cannot be achieved the expected scenario then can you recommend other ways which can do that?

Comment: Since likers return the array, why you can not simply display this in template in way `{{ likers.length }}` ?

Comment: Ok you get the points, save my whole days to solve this. Thank a lot

Answer (score 0):

I have the returned array with likers. But at beginning i never though using this could be achieved my goal. So this {{ likers.length }} actually can show the total number.

Comment: This is true for your case. However, it's good to note the number of likes may be inaccurate at the time of the new like. I would suggest making an ajax call to re calculate the likers again to get an accurate figure as, for example, 10 users may have liked/unliked in the time before the action.